# It is possible to export Tx Hash to a .txt file?

Tags: transactions

As above: It is possible to export a Tx Hash to a .txt file ?

For Example :
I'm using Geth Java console, I make a Transaction from my Account receving

> "0x123456789"

It is possible to send "0x123456789" to txhash.txt ?

Further Informations:
I usually started with

geth --datadir C:\Users\BulldogBud\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chainda‌​ta --networkid 3 console 2>>log.txt

then

web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x9876", "mypassword", 24*3600 ) In order to keep the account open from Java console without all the "Sync messages". In this way after the web3.personal.sendTransaction() command, how can I pass the Tx Hash out of the Java console?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try to use the `--exec` option for geth :

```
geth --exec  "eth.sendTransaction({from:"0x4ae4ddbf073ff57e5861490d72f9177d9039428a",to:"0x32f5f2a0deaada272387573dbf30894805de082c",value:10})" >> c:\\ether.txt console
```

Comment: Thank you Badr for your reply, I usually started with:

geth --datadir C:\Users\BulldogBud\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\testnet\chaindata --networkid 3 console 2>>log.txt

then

web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x9876", "mypassword", 24*3600 )

In order to keep the account open from Java console without all the "Sync messages".

In this way after the web3.personal.sendTransaction() command, how can I pass the Tx Hash out of the Java console?

Thanks a lot

Comment: @BulldogBud post it as a new question or edit this question.